# Facebook style status input border

Tags: html, css, facebook, input

I tried to figure it out using Firebug, but no chance. How is the Facebook status input border wrapped round the autosize input? Particularly, I am interested in the small triangle joined into the border. Using Firebug, I managed to find the triangle itself, which is provided in the form of a GIF image:

```
.uiComposerAttachment, .nub {
    background: url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/zf/r/PfBgtiydy5U.gif) no-repeat center top;
    height: 7px;
    width: 11px
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    top: 18px;
}
```

But I couldn't figure out how it is placed above the input and how the border is added, in the form of a background image or defined as a CSS border?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can do it using only CSS: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/22/css-quick-tip-css-arrows-and-shapes-without-markup/

A similar question has been asked before though...

Comment: stumbled upon this: http://css3shapes.com/ - great collection/ideas on how to get the various shapes including the speech bubble :)

Answer (score 5):

I made a fiddle that mimics the facebook status box...

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/mFuD4/5/

I added some functionality to the example, in particular, [I found a cool jQuery plugin that allows for textarea auto-resizing](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/).

Facebook actually uses a `<textarea>` element and the way they take care of the border is simple.

[image: Facebook status]

The "What's on your mind?" text is inside the `<textarea>` element and the border around it is due to several `<div>` element wrappers (more than the 2 I've shown above). Also, as you pointed out, the little arrow on top of the "What's on your mind?" is a `.gif` image, but there are ways to do this using only CSS!

### Regarding the triangle...

If you're interested in alternative ways to do this using only CSS, I asked a question recently about the little triangle! Here's the question...

[How can I create a "tooltip tail" using pure CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623072/css-craziness-and-a-new-challenge)

... and here are the answers:

- [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623072/css-craziness-and-a-new-challenge/5624017#5624017)
- [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623072/css-craziness-and-a-new-challenge/5623454#5623454)
- [answer 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623072/css-craziness-and-a-new-challenge/5623898#5623898)
- [answer 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623072/css-craziness-and-a-new-challenge/5633146#5633146) (this one is REALLY cool!!!)

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Answer (score 1):

The border around the textarea is actually around parent div's (.uiTypeahead, .wrap) within the form. Looks like the actual textarea has no border.

As for the triangle it is just a css background inside the li (the items status, photo, video, link, etc are a list). The triangle is this element: `<i class="nub"></i>`. It is then positioned absolute to sit at the bottom of the list which has the form just below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your useful hints,

I finally managed to solve it in a four-liner:

```
#type_indicator { /* img#type_indicator is the triangle image tag, followed by the input field in HTML code */
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
}
```

Greetings

Chris