# How do you create this triangle thingy?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

[image]

How does one create the triangle thing for a container that points to something? Is it photoshop?

Comment: It's an image (with css), yes, unless it's a CANVAS drawing.

Comment: i don't think there is pure css for this, at least not css2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can [be done in pure CSS](http://www.vitohuang.info/blog/2010/02/21/using-css-border-to-draw-shapes/), but an image would be the more sane option.

HTML:

```
<div id="bubble">
    Yes we can
    <div id="arrow"></div>
    <div id="arrow-border"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bubble {
    border:2px solid #036;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
}

#arrow {
    border-color: #036 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:20px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-40px;
    left:20px;
}

#arrow-border {
    border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:20px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-37px;
    left:20px;
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution and doesn't seem that insane at all

Comment: Related: [CSS craziness and a new challenge :)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5623072)

Comment: the major drawback is that you need to mess with the markup to do it, but, it's still pretty neat.

Comment: The only thing I wish is that the actual solution was part of the answer text.

Comment: Do I get two more wishes? :P Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look here:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

The image that makes the tooltip thingy you're looking at is found here:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/img/tooltip/black_arrow.png

[image]

For a CANVAS (non-image) version, see jQuery's BeautyTips:

http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html

CANVAS is like drawing to the screen. Don't ask me for an example, since I've never used it and I'm not real sure how it works. :P Note, browser support may be an issue with CANVAS.