# Is there a way to create a tail in a bubble with HTML 5?

Tags: html, css

[image]

For years, I have just saved the image as a background or cut the tail part and use that as the background; I have always used an image when coding on websites. Is there a way to do it without using an image now? I can create the box with rounded corners using CSS, but how can I make the tail?

Comment: here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623072/css-craziness-and-a-new-challenge/5624017#5624017

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this;
http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can make: See the demo:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo