# Pure CSS tooltip without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a “tooltip tail” using pure CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623072/how-can-i-create-a-tooltip-tail-using-pure-css)

I would like to create a Facebook/ Twitter style tooltip (that thing when you hover over people's profiles and there's a short summary of their profile). I came across a lot of tutorials but they use jQuery. Is there a way to do this is CSS and maybe javascript?

+I'd like for this to work on images as well.

Thanks

Comment: @GeorgeStocker not a duplicate. The word 'tooltip' is a red herring, the question is about creating triangles with CSS.

Comment: @stijn best thing for you to do is to edit it based on what it's really asking without invalidating the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with pure css

You can use the hover pseudo class to trigger it.

Here is a general concept that should get you started

```
div.profile-on-hover { display: none }
a:hover + .profile-on-hover { display: block }

<a>hover me</a>
<div class="profile-on-hover">bunch of stuff</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AsKpv/

the div will need to follow the a tag for the '+' to work with CSS

if you want to make it snazzy you could use opacity: 0 and opacity:1 with a css3 transition to make it fade in as well.

good luck

Comment: Love Jesse the cat! 