# change jQuery tooltip function to pure javascirpt

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm working with `Bootstrap 4.6` and I want to change the `function` in my `script` to pure `javascript`. I don't want to use jQuery because my complete code is written in pure javascript.

How I'm able to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
    <input data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
    <input data-toggle="tooltip" title="Not Hooray!">
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to study their jquery plugin then traslate it into pure js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize Tooltips in Bootstrap 4 with pure JavaScript? No jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61039512/how-to-initialize-tooltips-in-bootstrap-4-with-pure-javascript-no-jquery)

Comment: That's no problem. You seem to know how to write code that does not rely on jQuery, just re-implement jquery-tooltip from scratch and you're good.

Comment: See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.6.1/js/dist/tooltip.js for the source of bootstraps tooltip component.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359193/plain-javascript-tooltip here is already answer of your question