# How to display the data from database through tooltip?

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp, tooltip

i want to display the data from ajax request to tooltip, it's open in modal window right now, but I want to open it into the tooltip, how can I do that, I tried a lot but didn't get success, I stucked at here, please help me to show data through tooltip.

this is my view code

```
  echo $this->Manager->link('Groups',array('action'=> 'test_contact_group', $records['Contact']['contact_id']),array('class'=>'ajax_links'));
```

the html of this link is

```
   <a class="ajax_links" help="a" href="/contacts/test_contact_group/78">Groups</a>
```

and jquery is there

```
     <script>
$(".ajax_links").hover(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",   
        url: link,
        cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) { 

        jQuery('#myModal').modal('show');
        jQuery('.modal-body').html("Groups" + html);

    });
});


</script>
```

it is diplay in modal window, but I want to open it in tooltip, how can I do that, please help me. thanks a ton in advance, I really stucked here.

Comment: good question, really help ful for others

Comment: you want tooltip as text ? or a modalWindow?

Comment: I want to tooltip as a text

Comment: Does the .done() function gets called?

Comment: Also, change from "POST" to "GET"

Comment: no matter post or get because data is save in file through ajax request

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you..

```
$(".ajax_links").hover(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",   
        url: link,
        success : function (data){
        $('#elementId').attr('title',data);
        } 

    });
});
```

Comment: basically I want to display the data which is in view file not in attribute, the data is came from another function.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is only with jquery syntax, you can try this:

```
   $(this).attr("title", html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modal window. you just have a container for div with id tooltip. like this. then append the results.  some thing like this : demo [tooltip.](http://jsfiddle.net/CTtcD/) and CSS taken from this answer [Pure CSS Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623072/how-can-i-create-a-tooltip-tail-using-pure-css)

```
$('#toolTip').show();
```

Working demo : [DEMO for Tooltip](http://jsfiddle.net/CTtcD/)

or you can append to title attribute.

```
 $('#elementId').attr('title',data);
```

Comment: not work in my scenario the date is in another view which come from another function, data view file is other and link file is different