# (Down) Arrow Box with CSS

Tags: css, arrows

I want to do what [this arrow box does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180107/arrow-box-with-css), but instead of an arrow pointing to the right, I want it to point downward.

I've tried something like this: [jsfiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/thematejka/hbzHZ/)

```
#triangle-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 150px solid transparent;
    border-right: 150px solid transparent;
    border-top: 30px solid red;
}
#body {
    background-color: red;
    width:300px;
}

<div id="body">
     <h2>Title</h2>

    <p>this is text.</p>
</div>
<div id="triangle-down"></div>
```

It tends to be unreliable in terms of lining up the two divs. I'd like a one div solution.

Comment: Could you submit a picture for the arrow shape you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are... added some base styles for multiple posible directions as well...
http://jsfiddle.net/hbzHZ/16/

Uses two alternatives, one with inner `div`, another with pseudo-element `:after`

Comment: I like this one very much! Easy to modify and understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:after` pseudo-element with the same styles plus `display: block; content: ""; background-color: white` (or whatever the BG is actually supposed to be).

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/hbzHZ/15/

Answer (score 0):

Here you have http://jsfiddle.net/bqX3S/28/
The point is to use the same width and top value

```
width: 100px;
top: 100px;
```

So if change #arrow width you need to change top in for :after and :before elements as well