# Aligning css arrow boxes

Tags: css, css-shapes

My question is similar to this question: [Arrow Box with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180107/arrow-box-with-css) But instead of only 1 box I need to align several boxes. And still be able to see the arrow on all boxes.

In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/casperskovgaard/LHHzt/1/ I have created two arrow boxes that float to the left. The problem is that the arrow on the first box is not visible.

How do I make the arrow visible?

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow {
    float: left;
    width: 128px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position: relative;
}
.arrow:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 128px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.arrow:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 129px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #999;
}
```

**EDIT:**

The first arrow must overlap the box to the right. See solution from artSx: http://jsfiddle.net/LHHzt/6/ Only thing missing from this solution is that it should be possible to add several (more than two) boxes

Comment: Please check my answer, I think my fiddle shows what you are after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change the z-index of the after psudeo element to 2 and then the before element to 1 then it should work as you intend:

```
.arrow {
    float: left;
    width: 128px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position: relative;
    margin-right:15px;
}
.arrow:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 128px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.arrow:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 129px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #999;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/LHHzt/15/

Answer (score 1):

add this :

```
.arrow:first-child{
 z-index:10;   
}
```

[JsFiddle with correction](http://jsfiddle.net/LHHzt/6/)

Comment: This is the way it should look. But I also need to be able to add more boxes. If I add more boxes only the first and the last arrow is visible.

Comment: you can select arrow if you want => .arrow:nth-child(1) / .arrow:nth-child(2) etc..

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `z-index`to your `.arrow:before`. Here is the live version http://jsfiddle.net/LHHzt/13/

```
.arrow:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 129px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    z-index:2;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #999;
}
```

Works with as many box as you want :)

Comment: This is close to what I need. But this way the arrows change color. They need to stay the same color as the box. Only the border should be dark grey.

Comment: @CasperSkovgaard : Plz check this out http://jsfiddle.net/LHHzt/17/, i seems to be ok. Just add a z-index:2 to `.arrow:after` and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/casperskovgaard/LHHzt/1/

```
.arrow {
    width: 128px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position: relative;
}
.arrow:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 128px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.arrow:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 129px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #999;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you posted the right code. But the boxes need to be beside each other.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `margin` to the arrow...

```
.arrow {
    float: left;
    width: 128px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LHHzt/11/

Or change `z-index` to display above if you want them to overlay

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a margin to the arrow resolves the problem.

See this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LHHzt/9/

I just added a

```
margin-right: 15px;
```