# What is this called, and how do i replicated it in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I know the title stinks, but as it says i have no idea what the name is for what i want to create.

I want to do a list of links (or rather a menu if you prefer, but with no drop down), that looks like this:

[image: example of a menu i want to create]

This is just an example so it isnt very pretty. Its having those arrows in each box, and have them "connected" to eachother, but each box is an individual element. I think this type of style has a name, what is it called? Will help greatly searching for help.

I wish to achieve this by making the elements purely by CSS, and the closest i have come is help from this page: http://www.css3shapes.com/ but i just cant combine them to create the menu.

Any and all kinds of help is appreciated.

Comment: A CSS Arrow Box
see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180107/arrow-box-with-css

Comment: I'm not sure of the translation, but are you talking about breadcrumbs ?

Comment: It's called BradCrumbs. Original name from the old tale.

Comment: I wouldn't call these breadcrumbs necessarily. They don't have to be for navigation. They have many names, including "arrow box" and "steps."  Check out http://semantic-ui.com/elements/step.html as another example.

Comment: May be we can called it Arrow box serving as breadcrumbs..http://jsfiddle.net/6aH75/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used to call it `breadcrumbs with arrowboxes`. But its up to you. I dont think there is a generic name.
Check out these links
- http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-breadcrumbs
- http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-breadcrumb-navigation

Answer (score 2):

It's called BreadCrumbs.

It's easier to "paint" it than you think.

Here's a tip:

This is a single arrow:

[image]

And the magic:

[image]