# CSS tooltip tail with image

Tags: html, css

Tooltip tails in CSS are possible, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623072/how-can-i-create-a-tooltip-tail-using-pure-css). I am looking to do similar CSS tooltip tails, but with a background image. See for example Twitter's card tooltip (look in the top-left corner):

[image]

How can I do image tooltip tails?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to - do you mean the top _left_ corner of the map, under the user's image?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Beejamin: Yes, I mean top left. Corrected.

Comment: @putvande: I've tried using `background-image` but the tail and the body are discontinuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it using SVG and clip-path (just like twitter did)

### [Here's Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/szechr3v/)

It uses an `img` element and then it's masked. You can create the element using an [online tool](http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator) or free svg editor like [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/)

```css
.tooltip{
  width:380px;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position:center;

  /*Chrome,Safari*/
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(58px 25px,70px 9px,81px 25px,380px 25px,380px 215px,11px 215px,10px 25px);

  /*Firefox*/
  clip-path: url("#clipPolygon");

}


body{
  background:url('http://ericasadun.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/f.png');
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
    <polygon points="56 25,70 9,81 25,380 25,380 215,11 215,10 25">
    </polygon>
  </clipPath>
</svg>


<img class="tooltip" src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/animals-q-c-640-480-3.jpg" alt="">
```

http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator

Comment: Adding `border-radius` for the top two corners seems tricky... Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use css. You have to create a vector shape with rounded corners. Again i recommend inkscape. [Here's a tutorial](http://superuser.com/questions/640954/inkscape-rounding-corners-of-shapes)